# Could not find the firebase_core FlutterFire plugin error displayed when building Flutter project

Tags: flutter, firebase-mlkit, mlvision

I got following error when building flutter project:
*A problem occurred evaluating project ':firebase_ml_vision'.

> Could not find the firebase_core FlutterFire plugin, have you added it as a dependency in your pubspec*

Does it mean that I have to install some additional libraries? I just want to use ML Vision in my project. Thank you for any help.

My **pubspec.yaml** file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  get: ^3.24.0

  firebase_ml_vision: ^0.11.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.3+4
  image_cropper: 1.0.2
```

build.gradle (app):

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.grobonet"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
```

build.gradle (project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`firebase_core`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwirrLyhkN3vAhU0hv0HHSbOCr4QFjAAegQIAhAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpub.dev%2Fpackages%2Ffirebase_core&usg=AOvVaw0FLftN7ZoY1jQNlFhGpBIL) to your project.

Comment: after adding I have another error:

Because every version of integration_test from sdk depends on meta 1.3.0-nullsafety.6 and firebase_core >=1.0.0 depends on meta ^1.3.0, integration_test from sdk is incompatible with firebase_core >=1.0.0.
So, because grobonet depends on both firebase_core ^1.0.2 and integration_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because grobonet depends on both firebase_core ^1.0.2 and integration_test any from sdk, version solving failed.)

Comment: it's a new error, meaning that the current version of dependencies aren't working together, either downgrade some or upgrade some. Are you using Flutter with null-saftey? Try using `firebase_core: ^0.7.0`

Comment: Or use `get: ^4.1.1` with `firebase_core: ^1.0.2`. These are causing your error, try them and report back please.